# html 5 - mp4 video plays in Chrome but not IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, mp4

```
<div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video controls class="embed-responsive-item">
        <source src="~/AspxCommon/vids/mySearch.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
</div>
```

This code works perfect in Chrome, however, for some reason IE11 doesn't play the mp4 file when the play button is clicked. It displays the image below in IE11, and won't play.

[image: Click here for img]

Comment: can you share the video? it may be an encoding issue

Comment: Seems like issue with video, can you please share video, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/p95jo6ek/1/) jsfiddle works fine in IE 11

Comment: Instead of posting "thank you!" posts (which will be deleted), standard practice is to ***accept an answer*** . You can do this by hovering beside the answer until a checkmark appears, and click the checkmark. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. When you have 15 rep you can also upvote answers. You can only accept one answer per question, but upvote many.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should have other video formats available (.webm/.ogg) but for the purposes of demonstration I have commented mine out.

```css
video{
  width:350px;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<video id="mainVideo" preload="none" controls width="100%">

<!--  <source src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/nature.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/nature.webm" type="video/webm">-->
  <source src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/nature.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

The above code is saved in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0n54fxjz/) and it has been tested on IE 11.

The issue therefore is most likely not an IE issue, but either a) an issue with ***the file itself*** or b) something to do with the classes associated with the div (could you post the css?)

The first one is likelier, so check that your video file is okay. I would also recommend that you convert it to webm and ogg file types.

Hope this helps

Comment: Note: if your file is/was  a mov file, that has had it's suffix changed to mp4, you will need to convert the original file. Mov files are not supported by the video tag

Comment: there are many converter tools. depending on the size of the file you can either convert online, or download handbrake. Handbrake can convert larger files (and also compress them) and it's a free download afaik https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that IE expects the moov atom inside the mp4 file to be at the start of the file, while Chrome does not care.    The moov atom is typically at the end of the file.   If your encoding with FFMPEG, add -movflags faststart and it will move the moov atom to the start of the file.

Answer (score -2):

Use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`
The X-UA-Compatible meta tag allows Internet Explorer 11 to rendered in brower modes.